# How to get a group of buttons to space evenly?

Tags: html, css

I have a box on my html/css page with 15 buttons in it separated into 3 rows of 5. I want to assign the space of the parent container so that the buttons take up the whole space of the parent and each take up an equal amount of space. What's the best way to achieve this?

I tried setting the box to a container with bootstrap, then assigning space inside it to the buttons in the three rows, which made the buttons a good size, and I was able to decently space them horizontally with this, but I can't figure out how to uniformly spread and size them so they take up the whole parent container.

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>b 1</button>
  <button>b 2</button>
  <button>b 3</button>
  <button>b 4</button>
  <button>b 5</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button>b 1</button>
  <button>b 2</button>
  <button>b 3</button>
  <button>b 4</button>
  <button>b 5</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button>b 1</button>
  <button>b 2</button>
  <button>b 3</button>
  <button>b 4</button>
  <button>b 5</button>
</div>
```